# Add text next to spotify embedded link

Tags: html

I'm trying to embed a Spotify playlist link and add text next to it (on the right)
What I can't figure out is, how to make the paragraph of text appear on the right of the link whith some space between them.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Listen to us on spotify</h1>
<p>
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/6PacuyET9wu53oPnOCH1hB" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
<style="float: left">
Text
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hDqB.png)

Comment: `<style="float: left">` isn’t valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reconsider the styling and restructure the iframe by putting:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/6PacuyET9wu53oPnOCH1hB" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" style="float: left"></iframe>
```

Also you can use the Figcaption property of css if you want to place the caption just on the bottom/top of the embeded thing.

```
 <figcaption>text</figcaption>
```

Answer (score 0):

As user4642212's comment, the styling is invalid.

Use this instead:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/6PacuyET9wu53oPnOCH1hB" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" style="float: left"></iframe>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/GRqJOzx)